# how do i use toggleClass to only have one div open at a time in Owl Carousel?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

[**DEMO**](http://eclipse2.com/demo/slider/test/)

```
$('.ca-more').on('click', function(event) {
$('.ca-more').parent().siblings('.ca-content-wrapper').removeClass('active2');
$(this).parent().siblings('.ca-content-wrapper').toggleClass('active2');
var $that = $('.ca-content-wrapper.active2');
$($that).toggleClass('clicked');
$($that).closest('.owl-item').toggleClass('parent').next().toggleClass('cousin');
return false; });
```

I've customized owl carousel to slide out a hidden div  when a button is clicked inside one the displayed div's.  When the hidden div slides out it pushes the other displayed divs to the right.  As of now, if i open one and then try opening another one, both stay open at the same time.  How do I have it where if I click on one it closes all the others?

```
<div class="item link">
            <div class="ca-item-main">
                <div class="transparent-right"></div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x525" class="img-responsive"/>
                <a href="#" class="ca-more smore">
                    <span class="more">></span>
                    <span class="less"><</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
              <div class="ca-content">
                <div class="ca-content-text">
                  <h2 class="movie-title">This is the h2 title</h2>
                  <h4 class="date-rating">This is the h4 title</h4>
                  <h4 class="before-netflix">Another h4 title</h4>
                  <a href="#" class="owl-trailer-link"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"> </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Button 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="owl-trailer-link">Button 2</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to remove `.clicked` class:

```
$('.ca-more').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.ca-more').parent().siblings('.ca-content-wrapper').removeClass('active2');
    $('.ca-content-wrapper.clicked').removeClass('clicked'); /* <- You forgot this */
    $(this).parent().siblings('.ca-content-wrapper').toggleClass('active2');
    var $that = $('.ca-content-wrapper.active2');
    $($that).toggleClass('clicked');
    $($that).closest('.owl-item').toggleClass('parent').next().toggleClass('cousin');
    return false;
});
```

I would also suggest to set only one `parent` class, there is no need to set `clicked` class at all. What you would need to change is something like this:

**Instead of:**

```
.ca-content-wrapper.clicked {
    height: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Use this:**

```
.parent .ca-content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Once you have `parent` class on container, you are able to style any element inside.

Comment: thank you!  your code and advice pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

try closing all of the siblings before opening the one you clicked

```
 $('.ca-more').parent().siblings('.ca-content-wrapper').hide().removeClass('active2');
```